# Apache2: SSL not working

Tags: apache2, ssl

I have a 16.04.03 LTS server up and running. Apache2 is running as serving the website http://magmaguy.com just fine. I installed a SSL cert from LetsEncrypt using Certbot. However we still can not connect to the site with SSL.

"a2enmod SSL" is on
the site is enabled

files: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/magmaguy.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin *******
        DocumentRoot /var/www/magmaguy.com/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        ServerName magmaguy.com
        ServerAlias www.magmaguy.com

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/magmaguy.com-0002/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/magmaguy.com-0002/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin *****
        DocumentRoot /var/www/magmaguy.com

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        ServerName magmaguy.com
        ServerAlias www.magmaguy.com
# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.magmaguy.com [OR]
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =magmaguy.com
# RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

There is nothing about SSL in the /var/logs/apache/error.log

netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN shows :::80 and :::443 as listening for Apache2

How can I get SSL working?

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the very same problem. Have you been able to fix it in the meantime?

Comment: Connect with curl to the server: curl https://yourserver. Do you see error? You can enable ssl-logging: LogLevel info ssl:warn

Answer (score 0):

As per any [tutorial on enabling SSL in apache2](https://www.arubacloud.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-https-protocol-with-apache-2-on-ubuntu-20-04.aspx), you'd also need to enable the default Virtual Hosts and Headers module for the ssl after you're enabling the SSL Module.

So after you run :

```
$ sudo a2enmod ssl
```

You should also run :

```
$ sudo a2enmod headers
$ sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```